# How to change UITableView's appearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

What different kinds of things can you do to edit a tableview's appearance and how would you do them? For example, how would you change the color programmatically? Or change the navigation bar's color programmatically?

Comment: Way too broad a question. Is there something specific you’re trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs for [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You probaby want to change the backgroundColor property or customize each cells contentView property.  Also,look into layers, you can do things like make rounded corners, shadows, etc on a views layer.

Here is the [QuartzCore Framework docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad_login.html).  They should be useful if your trying to change the appearance of a view.

---

Edit (good suggestion bshirley):

[AboutTableViewsiPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: Particularly the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on UITableView particularly the configuring A Table View section.

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

or You can use,

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[colorWithRed:.98 green:.98 blue:.82 alpha:1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the appearance of all TableViews in your app you can define it with the Appearance property. In Monotouch you do something like this:

```
UITableView.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
UITableViewCell.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
```

In objective C it would be something similar.